# Flash, ActionScript 3: define a variable as a variable from its creator without constantly using creator.var 

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, composition

I am trying to split up my code in classes. but there is a issue what really bothers me. when i create a class for functions i am giving its own stage. like this

```
dragf:Dragfunctions = new Dragfunctions(this)
```

and in the class i use this

```
var stage:Object;

    public function Dragfunctions(stage:Object) 
    {
            this.stage = stage;
    }
```

as you  can see i can now call a variable of the stage using stage.var1 = "hi"
but when i need to ajust that varable many times it gets a quite messy...

there is a way to tell that when i call var1 he knows i mean stage.var1 without need to call stage. its:

```
var var1 = stage.var1
```

and then using

```
stage.var1 = var1
```

but that is quite unhandy too is there a better way?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think perhaps your class design could do with a rethink. Perhaps your stage is some sort of display object, and I assume that Dragfunctions is a class that provides some sort of drag functionality to that display object. It might be better to make a subclass of DisplayObject (or Sprite etc) and to implement the drag functions there instead. You won't then need to tunnel the DisplayObject properties through your Dragfunctions class. Generally, if you need to reimplement the interface of your contained class instance in the container, inheritance might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use getters and setters (which provide field-like semantics, but allow you to execute custom logic when assignment is used):

```
function set var1(val:SomeType):void
{
    stage.var1=val;
}
function get var1():SomeType
{
    return stage.var1;
}
function doStuff():void
{
    var1=new SomeType();  //this results in call to "set" method
    var st:SomeType=var1; //this results in call to "get" method
}
```